# Redirect user from site core link

Tags: webforms, sitecore

I have a webform application and I want only users to access my webpage if they are redirecting from site core page. Link of application is in a page in site core.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the referrer link to see if it can refer to the site core url.